# SUNWspro compiled file - detect verison of compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, solaris, sparc

I have a file, compiled by SUNWspro (Sun pro complier) for SPARC/Solaris. How can I detect version of compiler used to build this binary?

Comment: " strings -a file.exe|grep -i sun " gives @(#)sunmath.h   1.10    93/11/14
.SUNW_version
/..[home dir of author];/opt/SUNWspro/bin/../SC4.0/bin/f77

Comment: Another grep: "acomp: SC4.0 18 Oct 1995 C 4.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, it likes to be an "DevPro SC4.0 fortran compiler".

Comment: hey, but what was a commercial name?
And where can I get migration manual to the newer fortrans ?

Comment: DevPro 4.0 was the name of the Sun compilers about 15 years ago.
See for instance http://sunsolve.sun.com/search/document.do?assetkey=1-21-102699-01-1 from 1995.  The name has changed several times since - most recently they've been called the Sun Studio compilers, and are up to version 12 now -- more information is at http://developers.sun.com/sunstudio/index.jsp